# When starting node.js app i get MongoError

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having an issue with a mongo database.

when I run the server, I keep getting this error, and i have exported the password.

```
{ [MongoError: auth fails] name: 'MongoError', errmsg: 'auth fails', ok: 0 }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check for these...

1. Have you set `auth = true` in your `etc/mongod.conf`.
2. You might be connecting to `test` database.

Also **check your role**.

```
db.addUser( { user: "admin", pwd: "admin", 
    roles: ["userAdminAnyDatabase"] } );
```

Role `userAdminAnyDatabase` allows for **users administration** only. It can be authenticated only to database **admin**.